# Dagger - how to share a provided object between service and fragment?

Tags: android, dagger

I am trying to provide `CarFactory` through this module so that I can use `CarFactory` objects between `Service` and `Fragment`.

```
@Module(includes = UnscopedModule.class)
public final class ThisModuleModule {
    @Provides
    @ServiceScope
    static CarFactory provideCarFactory() {
        return new CarFactory();
    }

    @Provides
    @ServiceScope
    static String provideReferrer() {
        return "referrer";
    }
}
```

For the initial implementation, I can inject `CarFactory` into `Service` but obviously I can't inject it into `Fragment` because `provideCarFactory` is bound to @ServiceScope. How can I make it so that `CarFactory` can be injected into both `Service` and `Fragment` - basically sharing a single object in two different scopes? If I add `@FragmentScope` below `@ServiceScope`, it says `Cannot use more than one @Scope`...

Do I have to make it @ApplicationScope to make it accessible from both Service and Fragment???

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would recommend making it @ApplicationScope.

When you read "scope", think of it as "Dagger-managed lifecycle": @FragmentScope means that Dagger keeps your object alive as long as the Fragment exists, and each new Fragment instance gets a new copy of each @FragmentScope thing. Likewise for @ServiceScope: A @ServiceScope object or binding will exist for each Service instance, and ideally will be garbage-collected once the service is destroyed. Of course, as far as Android is concerned, Fragments and Services can have overlapping lifecycles that are not tied to one another.

For this reason, it doesn't make sense for something to be both @FragmentScope and @ServiceScope at the same time: You want the object to live longer than both the Fragment and the Service, in order for it to be shared between the two. This typically means you want it to be in @Singleton scope, for which @ApplicationScope is often a synonym in Dagger.

Note that this means that objects in @Singleton or @ApplicationScope will never be garbage-collected, because Dagger will keep them around long enough that your Fragment and Service will always get the same instance. Consequently, it is important to minimize what you put in those broad scopes to keep your memory usage low.